# JQuery Mobile - changePage result: undefined

Tags: jquery, mobile, undefined

I'm having a strange problem with JQuery Mobile's changePage() function. I'm trying to load a .php page after a button has been clicked.

This is the code I'm using:

```
/* SUBMIT SEARCH FORM */
$('input#search-submit').click(function() 
{
  $.mobile.changePage("search.php");            
});
```

After clicking the button however it only loads a page displaying: undefined (the url in the browser however is the correct one: "http://somedomain.com/search.php"). And after refreshing the page it also displays the results just fine!

There are no errors or strange warnings on my console so i can't figure out why it is behaving this way...

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly the same problem, and found the answer in this question:

[Why am I seeing a value of "undefined" on screen when I submit form in jQuery Mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787461/why-am-i-seeing-a-value-of-undefined-on-screen-when-i-submit-form-in-jquery-mo)

To summarise - you need to make sure that the script you're submitting to returns a complete jQuery Mobile page - it needs all the usual jQuery mobile page elements, such as a div with `data-role="content"`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a basic HTML Format to that search.php. For example

**search.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title></title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
</head>
<body>
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
</body>
</html>
```