# How does one view PHP errors while debugging jQuery Mobile forms?

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

I have a bug in my PHP code that processes a form submission in my jQuery Mobile app. When I submit the form, the word "Undefined" shows up on the page, which makes sense since not a complete page is returned to jQuery Mobile.

This question summarizes this problem.
[Why am I seeing a value of "undefined" on screen when I submit form in jQuery Mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787461/why-am-i-seeing-a-value-of-undefined-on-screen-when-i-submit-form-in-jquery-mo)

My question is how can I view the PHP error that occurred? I do not have access to the PHP error log file because I am developing on a shared server. jQuery Mobile just puts "Undefined" on the screen and outputs no error message.

Comment: write any possible errors to a log and view the log, or if it's a compile error, just call the php script directly and see if any errors are displayed. Or are you expecting to pass the error back to jquery?

Comment: the error is occuring after a post request. how do i call that directly?

Comment: Not clear whether the error is caused by the code making the submit - for example if the submit is done via an event handlers or it done viar ajax. The "Undefined' may also be the result of executing the php code - this error shows up as 'Undefined variable'.

Comment: Just off hand without seeing any code, I would either write errors output by the script to a log or change the script to take GET variables and then call the script directly with a url including the GET variables with some values for each to see if you get an error. That is where I would start anyhow. Someone more experienced might have a better way. I also, instead of logging, pass back errors via json to the calling script and then just display it with an alert but I dont think that is what you're asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form submit likely defaults to using Ajax. You can force a new page request by specifying `data-ajax="false"` as an attribute on the `form` element. This might help you see what PHP is outputting to the page (if anything).

If PHP is not writing errors to the page by default, you might be able to use a combination of `ini_set('display_errors', 1)` and the [`error_reporting` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to get them to display as you'd like.

Comment: Thanks, that works! I can view the error when Ajax is turned off.