# jquery mobile href with php variable

Tags: php, jquery, mobile, href

im trying a bit with jquery mobile, and it works suprisingly good :D

but i have one problem with linking with href to a php with parameters:

if i do

```
echo "<a href='deletemessages.php?token=".$row['messagetoken']."'></a>";
```

it always returning in a new page with "undefined" on screen

but if i do it with a html file it works as it should do.

how to solve this?

regards

Comment: I suppose you are getting your $row['messagetoken'] as a result of database query, then make sure the echo is able to access that variable. And to make sure it is accessible, place it within the database data loop

Comment: if i check the sourcecode of the uploaded page the token is written correctly in the href link
href="deletemessages.php?token=123456TOKEN"

Comment: OK, thank you for the info. Then you should check this post which explains the trick (code validity and ajax call for instance)- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787461/why-am-i-seeing-a-value-of-undefined-on-screen-when-i-submit-form-in-jquery-mo

Comment: so i have to create a form around every link to send variables to a other php file?

Comment: I guess you should hook your link with ajax call to make sure that variables are passed and received properly

Comment: sorry but im dont familiar with ajax :(  how i can do that in combination with jquery mobile and a href link/button ?

Comment: The post included in the link explains it much better than I would so use it. The important thing is this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7788855/1071719